# Python: fuzzywuzzy matching dataframe but returns unpredictable results

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, mapping, matching, fuzzywuzzy

I've been searching around for a while now, but I can't seem to find the answer to this small problem.

I created this function to match words with the wrong result in the column by mapping the main column containing the correct word

```
data_provinsi = {'id':[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
        'name':['PAPUA', 'PAPUA BARAT', 'JAWA TIMUR', 'DKI JAKARTA', 'MALUKU', 'MALUKU UTARA']}

df_provinsi = pd.DataFrame(data_provinsi)
df_provinsi

data_geo = {'province_id':[11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13],
        'provinsi':['PAPUA', 'PAPUA', 'PAPUA BARAT', 'PAPUA BARAT', 'PAPUA BARAT',' PAPUA BARAT', 'PAPUA BARAT', 'JAWA TIMIR', 'JAWA TIMAR']}

df_sample = pd.DataFrame(data_geo)
df_sample

def checker(df_is_wrongs,col_is_wrong,df_correct_options,col_correct_options):
    names_array=[]
    ratio_array=[]    
    for word in df_is_wrongs[col_is_wrong]:
        if word in df_correct_options[col_correct_options]:
            names_array.append(word)
            ratio_array.append('100')
        else:   
            x=process.extractOne(word,df_correct_options[col_correct_options],scorer=fuzz.token_set_ratio)
            names_array.append(x[0])
            ratio_array.append(x[1])
    return names_array,ratio_array

name_match,ratio_match=checker(df_sample,'provinsi',data_provinsi,'name') #buat jalanin checker

df_sample['mapped_names']=pd.Series(name_match).astype(str) #bikin hasil mapping
df_sample['ratio'] = pd.Series(ratio_match).astype(int) #bikin ratio kebenarannya
```

however, after trying the function, there are some results that are changed even though the word is still correct according to the data mapping column data. such as index 5 ('PAPUA' AND 'PAPUA BARAT' data). The 2 words are still true but have changed.

```
>>> output
    province_id   provinsi  mapped_names    ratio
0   11             PAPUA       PAPUA        100
1   11             PAPUA       PAPUA        100
2   11          PAPUA BARAT   PAPUA BARAT   100
3   12          PAPUA BARAT   PAPUA BARAT   100
4   12          PAPUA BARAT   PAPUA BARAT   100
5   12          PAPUA BARAT    PAPUA        100
6   12          PAPUA BARAT  PAPUA BARAT    100
7   13          JAWA TIMIR    JAWA TIMUR    90
8   13          JAWA TIMAR    JAWA TIMUR    90
```

is there any other solution to fix this with simpler program code without looping? because it will take a long time to compute

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
best_match = lambda x: pd.Series(process.extractOne(x, df_provinsi['name'].unique()))
df_sample[['mapped_names', 'ratio']] = df_sample['provinsi'].apply(best_match)
print(df_sample)

# Output:
   province_id      provinsi mapped_names  ratio
0           11         PAPUA        PAPUA    100
1           11         PAPUA        PAPUA    100
2           12   PAPUA BARAT  PAPUA BARAT    100
3           12   PAPUA BARAT  PAPUA BARAT    100
4           12   PAPUA BARAT  PAPUA BARAT    100
5           12   PAPUA BARAT  PAPUA BARAT    100
6           12   PAPUA BARAT  PAPUA BARAT    100
7           13    JAWA TIMIR   JAWA TIMUR     90
8           13    JAWA TIMAR   JAWA TIMUR     90
```